# How to fix error in SimpleJdbcInsert in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I learn Spring Boot reading book Spring in Action 5. I try to insert data to H2 embedded database.I use SimpleJdbcInsert and executeAndReturnKey method.

Here is a Constructor:

```
 @Autowired
public JdbcOrderRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {

this.orderInserter = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbc).withTableName("Taco_Order").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    this.orderTacoInserter = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbc).withTableName("Taco_Order_Tacos");
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Here is methods to insert data:

```
@Override
public Order save(Order order) {

    order.setPlacedAt(new Date());
    long orderId = saveOrderDetails(order);
    order.setId(orderId);
    List<Taco> tacos = order.getTacos();

    for (Taco taco : tacos)
        saveTacoToOrder(taco, orderId);

    return order;
}

private long saveOrderDetails(Order order) {
    Map<String, Object> values = objectMapper.convertValue(order, Map.class);
    values.put("placedAt", order.getPlacedAt());
    long orderId = orderInserter.executeAndReturnKey(values).longValue();

    return orderId;
}
```

The error is on this string:

```
long orderId = orderInserter.executeAndReturnKey(values).longValue();
```

Error text:

```
 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
PreparedStatementCallback; ???????? NULL ?? ????????? ??? ???? 
"DELIVERYNAME" NULL not allowed for column "DELIVERYNAME"; SQL statement: 
INSERT INTO Taco_Order (DELIVERYNAME, DELIVERYSTREET, DELIVERYCITY, 
DELIVERYSTATE, DELIVERYZIP, CCNUMBER, CCEXPIRATION, CCCVV, PLACEDAT) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-197]; nested exception is 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: ???????? NULL ?? ????????? ??? ???? 
"DELIVERYNAME" NULL not allowed for column "DELIVERYNAME"; SQL statement: 
INSERT INTO Taco_Order (DELIVERYNAME, DELIVERYSTREET, DELIVERYCITY, 
DELIVERYSTATE, DELIVERYZIP, CCNUMBER, CCEXPIRATION, CCCVV, PLACEDAT) 
   VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-197]
```

Bur in debugger evrything is alright:
value parameter is fully loaded by values.
[idea screensot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKTIj.jpg)

Class Order:

```
@Data
public class Order {

@NotBlank(message = "Name is required")
private String name;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is required")
private String street;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is required")
private String city;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is required")
private String state;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is required")
private String zip;

@CreditCardNumber(message = "Not valid cc")
private String ccNumber;

@Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$", message = "Must be formatted MM/YY")
private String ccExpiration;

@Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0, message = "Invalid CVV")
private String ccCVV;

private Long id;
private Date placedAt;

List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();

public void addDesign(Taco design) {
    this.tacos.add(design);
}

}
```

How to fix this problem and insert data to H2 database using SimpleJdbcInsert?

Comment: The message isn't clear?  *NULL not allowed for column "DELIVERYNAME";*

Comment: look at screenshot. Values are not Null

Comment: Can you please add Order class as well in post..

Comment: Added. I used Lombok for this

Comment: The javadoc of SimpleJdbcInsert says: *All you need to provide is the name of the table and a Map containing the column names and the column values.* Your table has a column named `DELIVERYNAME`. Is there any key named like that in the map you're creating? Your Order class has a property named `name`. I doubt tranforming an Order to a Map using ObjectMapper would magically turn that to a key named `DELIVERYNAME`.

Comment: Thank you! ObjectMapper make keys in Map named like fields in Order class. I changed SQL schema - field names in database are now equal to Map key. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue today. I was able to resolve this.

To fix this remove, go to schema.sql(file in which you are creating tables) and remove delivery from fields in Taco_Order table.

From book

> SimpleJdbcInsert has a couple of useful methods for executing the insert: execute() and executeAndReturnKey(). Both accept a Map, where the map keys correspond to the column names in the table the data is inserted into. The map values are inserted into those columns.

Keys name are fields from Order.java

Answer (score 0):

I went through the screen shot and i do not see any value for column `DELIVERYNAME`.

The issue is because of the table in which you are running the insert operation doesn't allow null values for the column `DELIVERYNAME`.

Ways to solve this:-

1. Remove the `NOT NULL` constraints from the column in the table definition.
2. Remove the `@NotBlank` annotation from the members of the object if you are not sure whether the data is going to be blank or not.
3. Use proper mapping between the column names in table and those with the member name in `Class/Entity` Definition. You can use `@Column` annotation to easily do that.

As much I can understand following your code and screenshot, that the issue is because of improper mapping between column names and that of the member of the object.
It is recommended that rather than relying on the auto mapping of Spring Boot coder should manually do the mapping using `@Column` annotation or mapping through hibernate configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with attributes name in Order class. These should mirror the coloumn name of respective table.
Eg:

private String deliveryName; -> would be mapped to deliveryName field in db.

The issue has arisen as in schema.sql the field is named as "deliveryName" while in ingredient class the attirbute is named "name".

Comment: please add bit more explanation to this answer

Comment: it can be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for those who follow the examples from book "Spring in action". You won't do such thing in real life, but if you're a reader of this book it is reasonable to replace this:

```
    Map<String, Object> values = objectMapper.convertValue(order, Map.class);
    values.put("placedAt", order.getPlacedAt());
```

with this:

```
        Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("ID", order.getId());
        values.put("PLACEDAT", order.getPlacedAt());
        values.put("DELIVERYNAME", order.getName());
        values.put("DELIVERYSTREET", order.getStreet());
        values.put("DELIVERYCITY", order.getCity());
        values.put("DELIVERYSTATE", order.getState());
        values.put("DELIVERYZIP", order.getZip());
        values.put("CCNUMBER", order.getCcNumber());
        values.put("CCEXPIRATION", order.getCcExpiration());
        values.put("CCCVV", order.getCcCVV());
```

Previous answers mentioned changing schema which will cause problems if you will follow examples from next chapters or using jpa annotations to perform mapping, but according to the author of the book you don't know about them because they are introduced in the next chapters. Besides you won't use JdbcOrderRepository class from the next chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Names of fields in Order class must be the same as columns names in table Taco_Order.

```
@Data
public class Order {
    private Long id;

    private Date placedAt;

    @NotBlank(message = "Podanie imienia i nazwiska jest obowiazkowe")
    private String deliveryName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Podanie ulicy jest obowiązkowe")
    private String deliveryStreet;

    @NotBlank(message = "Podanie miasta jest obowiązkowe")
    private String deliveryCity;

    @NotBlank(message = "Podanie województwa jest obowiązkowe")
    private String deliveryState;

    @NotBlank(message = "Podanie kodu pocztowego jest obowiązkowe")
    private String deliveryZip;

    @CreditCardNumber(message = "To nie jest prawidłowy numer karty kredytowej")
    private String ccNumber;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$", message = "Wartość musi być w formacie MM/RR")
    private String ccExpiration;

    @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0, message = "Nieprawidłowy kod CVV")
    private String ccCVV;

    public List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addDesign(Taco design) {
        this.tacos.add(design);
    }

    public List<Taco> getTacos() {
        return tacos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today and all I had forgotten to do was to update the fields in the order.html file to deliveryName, deliveryCity etc.